# RAID + IEEE1667 + TPM + UEFI

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm, bitlocker, uefi

Windows Server using a IEEE-1667 drive allows hardware based encryption on the fly.

What are our options when using two disks with a RAID controller, in order to achieve redundancy and parity (T10-DIF)? Is it possible, the booting RAID controller to support IEEE-1667 so that along with UEFI's Secure Boot and TPM, be able to enable hardware encryption? If not, can the RAID controller make a UEFI boot along with TPM handshake to ensure that everything is normal before decrypting the SED disks and loading the OS?

I found about eNova's X-Wall which is a transparent IEEE-1667 device between the HDD and the OS, but I haven't seen anything on RAID level.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the article [Windows 10’s BitLocker Encryption No Longer Trusts Your SSD](https://www.howtogeek.com/442114/windows-10s-bitlocker-encryption-no-longer-trusts-your-ssd/). While you can still make Windows to trust the drive hardware encryption, it may be preferable security-wise to do that at the software side. That would remove your need of a RAID controller supporting IEEE-1667, and would as well increase your recovery chances if the disk failed.

Comment: Thank you Angel for this heads up. I was aware for specific drives that were bypassed, but didn't know this specific policy. However, on server systems (where RAID is mostly used) is there a way we can secure with TPM the unlock of SED drives by the controller? In case someone steals an edge server on a branch, to make it impossible to access the data by dual booting the machine.